# How to add a restriction if else in my restaurants add to cart

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have an assignment of making add to cart foods of different restaurants but there is a bit problem where adding restrictions in adding food. My problem is when I add to cart food all of the restaurants can be added I wanted to have a 1 transaction per restaurant where when i add to cart a different restaurant food it will prompt a message that i have items in my cart in a different restaurant if i wanted to continue the cart will be unset and will add the new food in my cart. Please help thanks

I don't know where to place my if else statement to restrict the adding of food

```
        //check if Add to Cart button has been submitted
        if(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'add_to_cart')){
            if(isset($_SESSION['shopping_cart'])){
                //keep track of how many products are in the shopping cart
                $count = count($_SESSION['shopping_cart']);
                //create sequential array for matching array keys to products id's
                $product_ids = array_column($_SESSION['shopping_cart'], 'Product_ID');

                if(!in_array(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'p'), $product_ids)){
                    $_SESSION['shopping_cart'][$count] = array (
                    'Restaurant_ID' => filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'r'),
                    'Product_ID' => filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'p'),
                    'name' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name'),
                    'price' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'price'),
                    'quantity' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'quantity')
                    ); 
                }
                else { //product already exists, increase quantity
                    //match array key to id of the product being added to the cart
                    for ($i = 0; $i < count($product_ids); $i++){
                        if($product_ids[$i] == filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'p')){
                            //add item quantity to the existing product in the array
                            $_SESSION['shopping_cart'][$i]['quantity'] += filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'quantity');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else {//if shopping cart doesn't exist, create first product with array key 0
                //create array using submitted form data, start from key 0 and fill it with values
                $_SESSION['shopping_cart'][0] = array (
                'Restaurant_ID' => filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'r'),
                'Product_ID' => filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'p'),
                'name' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name'),
                'price' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'price'),
                'quantity' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'quantity')
                );        
            }
        }
      }
        ?>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: sorry im new here